# ¿Cómo puede cambiar el color de círculo de QRadioButton en PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Quiero cambiar el estilo de mi botón de radio (QRadioButton) en PyQt5. Ya he buscado muchas cosas por internet y no encuentro una solución concreta.

No quiero que sea de color negro el círculo al momento de que esté checado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usa slylesheets o accede a la paleta de colores del widget. Yo elegiría lo primero, es el camino más facil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa SlyleSheets:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
 
 
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        
        self.radioButton_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('radioButton_1')
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('radioButton_2')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioButton_1, 3, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.radioButton_2, 4, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.setRowStretch(5, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(2, 1)


QSS = """
QPushButton {
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    min-width: 180px;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: blue; /*white;*/
    border: 3px solid gray;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: #64b5f6;
}
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: #bbdefb;    
}

/* QRadioButton ----------------------------------------------------------- */
QRadioButton::indicator {
    border: 2px solid #a35709; 
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
QRadioButton::indicator:checked {
    background: qradialgradient(
        cx:.5, cy:.5, radius: .7,
        fx:.5, fy:.5,
        stop:0 '#ff8303', 
        stop:0.45 '#ff8303',
        stop:0.5 transparent,
        stop:1 transparent
    );
}
"""

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS) 
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me ayudaste con esto.

Comment: Sabes dónde podría estudiar PyQt5 a fondo, en la universidad me lo dieron brevemente.